# Qt - Disable editing of cell

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTableView` (model based) and I want to disable the editing capability of a particular cell, let's say row 0, column 1.

How can I do this? Please note that I still want other cells in this row enabled for editing.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a custom table model, you can implement the `Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const` method and return a set of flags where the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag is not set for the cells you do not want to edit. Suppose `MyTableModel` is inherited from `QAbstractTableModel`:

```
Qt::ItemFlags MyTableModel::flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const {
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::NoItemFlags;

    if (index.row() == 0 && index.column() == 1) {
       return flags;
    }
    return flags | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}
```

Comment: @Indraraj - You should probably write a comment here regarding the change you proposed. I almost rejected it.